# Verify Access Token Facebook?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am wondering how to verify the access token that facebook generates on login in my server? Also what information it contains

I followed [this page](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/accountkit/graphapi/) and did this

```
https://graph.accountkit.com/v2.7/me/?access_token=
```

but when I put my token in it says it is invalid oauth token

when I use this one I found

```
https://graph.facebook.com/app?access_token=
```

it brings back

```
{
   "category": "Lifestyle",
   "link": "http://localhost:3333/",
   "name": "testapp",
   "id": "2"
}
```

I am not sure if that is valid enough. I was hoping it would bring back user data as well.

Edit

I am using [this react plugin](https://github.com/keppelen/react-facebook-login) to do the facebook login it comes back with

```
accessToken: ""
email:""
expiresIn:4863
id: "" // think this is userId as it is the same numbr as UserId Field?
signedRequest:""
userID:""
```

Comment: You can not get user data back, if you are not using a user access token. Since your /me request gives back data about the app, you must be using an app access token.

Comment: @CBroe I am using react-facebook-login which gives me an "accessToken" but no "user token". I just the userID.